# With SQLModel how can I send an record with uuid field and let it be autogenerated in Postgres

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, sqlmodel

I am using SQLModel with FastAPI to insert data into Postgres.

The model I am using is

```
import uuid
from datetime import datetime, time
from typing import Optional
from uuid import UUID

from sqlmodel import Field, SQLModel, create_engine, Column, DateTime, JSON, text, MetaData

from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import UUID as UUIDSA

class LogsSessionSqlModel(SQLModel, table=True):
  __tablename__ = "foo"
  metadata = foo_metadata

  id: Optional[int] = Field(primary_key=True, index=True)
  description: str = Field(nullable=False, max_length=1024)
  created: Optional[datetime] = Field(sa_column=Column(DateTime(timezone=True),   nullable=False))
  uid: Optional[UUID] = Field(index=True, nullable=False, default=uuid.uuid4())
```

And this is the matching Postgres table.

[image: Postgres Table Columns]

If I don't provide the default value for uid, I get an error that the value cannot be null and if I provide a value, then Postgres is not the one to create it.

What is incorrect with the definition of uid field to make it so I don't have to provide a value when I insert a new line and let Postgres auto generate a value?

Answer (score 3):

This is the proper setting for the uid field of the table class.

Once I use the sa_column (SqlAlchemy column) in this way, then Postgres is providing the value as expected.

```
import uuid
from datetime import datetime, time
from typing import Optional
from uuid import UUID

from sqlmodel import Field, SQLModel, create_engine, Column, DateTime, JSON, text, MetaData

from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import UUID as UUIDSA


class LogsSessionSqlModel(SQLModel, table=True):
  __tablename__ = "sessions"
  metadata = logs_metadata
  __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}

  id: Optional[int] = Field(primary_key=True, index=True)
  description: str = Field(nullable=False, max_length=1024)
  created: Optional[datetime] = Field(sa_column=Column(DateTime(timezone=True), nullable=False))
  completed: Optional[datetime] = Field(
      sa_column=Column(DateTime(timezone=True), nullable=True)
  )
  uid: Optional[UUID] = Field(
      sa_column=Column(
          UUIDSA(as_uuid=True),
          server_default=text("gen_random_uuid()")
      ), default=None
  )
```